# Formula to find n numbers occuring together in a cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I would like to ask whether it is possible to create formula in Excel that extracts `n` first numbers in certain cell but only if these numbers are next to each other (in a group).

For instance for RegExp we can write `\d{8}` which in string:

> abc1234_123456789012abc_87654321000_abc

finds groups of every eight numbers occuring together no matter how many times they occur:

> abc1234_`12345678`9012abc_`87654321`_000abc

I would like to achieve similar effect (it may be even the first occurrence, not every) without using VBA (RegExp) and to have ability to easily change number of digits taken into account, i.e. from another cell, not by expanding the formula with additional functions.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Microsoft365, you could try:

[image]

For all overlapping values in `C1`:

```
=LET(A,MID(A1,SEQUENCE(LEN(A1)),B1),B,IF(ISNUMBER(--A),A,""),FILTER(B,B<>"",""))
```

For all non-overlapping sequences in `D1`:

```
=LET(A,B1,B,MID(A1,SEQUENCE(LEN(A1)),1),C,FILTERXML(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(CONCAT("<t><s>'",IF(ISNUMBER(--B),B," "),"</s></t>"))," ","</s><s>'"),"//s"),D,FILTERXML("<t><s>"&TEXTJOIN("</s><s>",,MID(C,SEQUENCE(1,LEN(A1),2,A),A))&"</s></t>","//s[string-length()="&A&"]"),TEXT(D,REPT(0,A)))
```

The 2nd option got quite long since I needed to find a way to prevend false positives when I checked if preceding tokens were numeric etc. But you'd only now need to change the value in `B1` to whichever number you'd like to find the non-overlapping values. For example:

[image]

---

To simply get the first occurence of any 8 digits, try:

```
=IFERROR(MID(A1,MATCH(1,INDEX((ISNUMBER(--MID(A1,ROW(A$1:INDEX(A:A,LEN(A1))),B$1)))*(LEN(MID(A1,ROW(A$1:INDEX(A:A,LEN(A1))),B$1))=B$1),),0),B$1),"Not Found")
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your wonderful solution. I try to understand it and I wonder what does tags <t> and <s> mean. I guess it's some xml parsing with length of string but I cannot find what they are for and how does that parsing work. I would be grateful if you could explain it briefly.

Also if it's not a problem could you modify your second "non-overlapping" formula to match it in one row? First occurence will be enough like in D1 (1234 for 4). My attempts were completely unsuccessful.
Thanks again!

Comment: Also unfortunately it turned out, that target computers don't have 365 license (but normal 2019), so "let" and "sequence" functions does not work. Will it be possible without these functions?

Comment: @Atex, I edited the answer to include an array formula that shoudl work in Excel 2019 and should return the first occurence of your number.

Comment: Thanks again. It almost works because it also returns shorter occurences or for multiple rows it returns also other characters as you can see there: https://i.imgur.com/b7ZvA3c.png

Comment: You are correct and I also did not anticipate on you dragging the formula down. In such a case you need (semi-)absolute references. Let me adjust the formula. @Atex

Comment: I noticed it doesn't require array formula anymore. I don't know why but it was a bit laggy despite the small amount of data. Everything works flawlessy now. Thank you very much for your help, you're great.

Comment: That's because I nested an `INDEX()` inside @Atex